# How send pending notifications that are newer than 24 hours not old on restart?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, notifications, queue, jobs

Need to modify notifications so that if the notification job does not run for some reason, then when we start it up again later it only sends pending notifications that are newer than 24 hours old. Reason being, when we restart the queue, we don't want anyone getting flooded with old notifications. They are time sensitive so if we miss them, after 24 hours they just need to not be sent.

```php
$this->dispatch(new SendOnboardingDocs($candidate));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `retryUntil` method to your job and set the timeout to 24hrs...

```
/**
 * Determine the time at which the job should timeout.
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function retryUntil()
{
     return now()->addHours(24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check your notification timestamp in SendOnboardingDocs, and if it older then 24 hours just skip it and remove your task from queues list

Comment: This is an example of sending my job to the queue. At the moment they are already in the queue. For some reason, I restarted the queues, but the job was pending. I need a mechanism to determine that they are already out of date for me.

Comment: so you can delete all tasks that out of date by event Before, so all tasks  don't get in job
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-events